# Sector-precise partition editor with resize NTFS?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, sectors

Is there a sector-precise partition manager that can resize an NTFS partition? Accepting Windows software and Live CDs.

Comment: The default cluster size of NTFS is 4KB - setting a size on sector-precision therefore would require to have an NTFS file-system with custom cluster size of 512 bytes (don't know if this is possible - I only know larger block sizes).

Comment: Physical sectors on new hard drives are 4KB, and erase blocks on SSDs are larger.  Partitions should be aligned to those sizes.  Windows' default 1MB partition alignment is a good compromise since it's a multiple of any sector or block size that a storage device is likely to use, but still rather small compared to the capacity of a modern storage device.

Comment: @Wyzard: Thankfully I am using an _old_ drive (physical 512 sectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure about "sectors," but `ntfsresize` from [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) lets you resize NTFS filesystems to kibibyte precision, which usually corresponds to two "sectors". Most *NIX partition tools, including `fdisk`, `parted` and `cfdisk` lets you resize the partition to increments of 512 bytes, corresponding to one "sector."

All, or a subset, of the above are available on most Linux live disks, I myself prefer the Gentoo live disks, available [here](http://mirrors.eu.kernel.org/gentoo/releases/amd64/11.2/).

Check the corresponding man pages for instructions to the individual programs.

PS: Apparently the native windows partitioning software (`diskpart`) only allows MiB precision.